# React Node.js with Spotify-web-api trouble getting playlist information

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, spotify

I'm building a small web app with React just to learn to use the Spotify API: https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node and following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prayNyuN3w0&t=1064s . But I've run into a problem. I have this function:

```
  getNowPlaying(){
    spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
          nowPlaying: { 
              name: response.item.name, 
              albumArt: response.item.album.images[0].url
            }
        });
      })  
  }
```

That properly returns what I am currently listening to. I also have this:

```
getUserPlaylist(){
    spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists('1242952295')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("This is the name of the 5th item in the response object: ", response.items[5].name);
  });
  }
```

That correctly returns the name of the 5th playlist on my profile.

However, neither of these functions return correct information about a specific playlist:

```
  getSlamsPlaylist(){
    spotifyApi.getPlaylist('1mJN7wfIm6NGYqniPuEKpJ') //5ieJqeLJjjI8iJWaxeBLuK (from example)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

  getSlamsPlaylistV2(){
    spotifyApi.getPlaylist('1mJN7wfIm6NGYqniPuEKpJ') //5ieJqeLJjjI8iJWaxeBLuK (from example)
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log('Some information about this playlist', data.body);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
    });
  }
```

The first one returns simply: "uncaught exception: Object" while the second returns that the playlist id was invalid even though I have tried several correct ones. Also, in the data that is returned from the "getUserPlaylist()" method I can see that the id's that I'm using are correct.

Also, this returns undefined as well:

```
getUserPlaylistV2(){
    spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists('1242952295')
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log('Some information about this playlist', data.body);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
    });
  }
```

What am I missing to make this work?

Console.log results of  getSlamsPlaylist():
uncaught exception: Object

Console.log results of getSlamsPlaylistV2():

```
Something went wrong! 
XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: onreadystatechange(), readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/7CoPUH1fJFKzcc7NAIv9XU/playlists/undefined", status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", responseType: "", response: "{\n  \"error\" : {\n    \"status\" : 404,\n    \"message\" : \"Invalid playlist Id\"\n  }\n}" }
```

I can give more info on this one if I need.

Console.log result of getUserPlaylistV2():
Some information about this playlist undefined

Comment: It would sure help if we saw the console.log results

Comment: I edited the question I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

well, give this a try

```
import SpotifyWebApi from "spotify-web-api-js";

const spotify = new SpotifyWebApi();
spotify.setAccessToken(_token);

spotify.getUserPlaylists().then((playlists) => {    
    console.log(playlists);
});

spotify.getPlaylist("37i9dQZF1E36tW5bkWLjXH").then((playlist) => {
        console.log(playlist);
});
```

It worked for me